# OnPlatform tags not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm using Xamarin Studio 6.1, recently upgraded it to work with a Xamarin Forms project. I can't seem to get the OnPlatform tags working. I'm trying something like this

```
<Grid Padding="12">
    <Grid.HeightRequest>
        <OnPlatform />
    </Grid.HeightRequest>
</Grid>
```

The previewer immediately breaks and complains Invalid XAML: Type `OnPlatform not found in xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"`

I've never seen this error before and can't find any help online. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It might because of not specifiying `TypeArguments`. Try this:

```
<Grid.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
      iOS="15" Android="10" WinPhone="10"/>
</Grid.HeightRequest>
```

**Update:**

The syntax above is deprecated. The new form is:

```
<Grid.HeightRequest>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="15"/>
        <On Platform="Android" Value="10"/>
        <On Platform="WinPhone" Value="10"/>
    </OnPlatform>
</Grid.HeightRequest>
```

Comment: It now says `Invalid XAML: Type Double not found in xmlns`

Comment: put a `x` namespace identifier for `Double` like `x:Double`

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. sometimes I'm such a noob